# Problem on telethon events and using them separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

This is my code - pay attention to nots(numbers)

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="test")) # 1
async def wait(event):
    chat = event.chat_id
    txw = "some text" 
    await bot.send_message(chat, txw, buttons = [Button.inline("help", b"help")]) # 2
    bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats = chat)) #3
    async def get(event):
        txt = event.raw_text #4
        bot.remove_event_handler(get) # 6
        if not len(txt) == 10:
            await event.reply("false information") # 5
        if len(txt) == 10:
            await event.reply("created seccessfuly")
```

The 1 is receiving the message (test) and 2 sends message successfully.

But the problem is 3, 4, 5. 3 gets the message (test) but I want to just 1 get test message and 3 get another message and after remove the handler after getting the message with 10 len.

Comment: You should use the `!=` operator for the first comparison (and probably `else` for the second). I encourage you to read some basic Python tutorials first.

Comment: Tryed every think you sed not solved

Answer (score 0):

events are treated sequentially so after the first event finished running it will run the second one that you just created(the get event). you can add an if check inside the get(event) to special case this.

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="test")) # 1
async def wait(event1):
    chat = event1.chat_id
    txw = "some text" 
    await bot.send_message(chat, txw, buttons = [Button.inline("help", b"help")]) # 2
    bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats = chat)) #3
    async def get(event2):
        if event2.id == event1.id:
             # this means that we are treating the message we got from event1.
             return
        txt = event2.raw_text #4
        bot.remove_event_handler(get) # 6
        if not len(txt) == 10:
            await event.reply("false information") # 5
        if len(txt) == 10:
            await event.reply("created seccessfuly")
```